# If the support of a module defines a graph of some map, is the module finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

**My Question**

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $A$, $B$ be integral domains of finite type over $k$.

If $M$ is an $A \otimes_k B$ module such that

- finitely generated as an $A \otimes_k B$ module
- for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$, there exist a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{q} \subset B$ such that $M \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{p} \cong B/\mathfrak{q}$ as $B$ module

then is $M$ finitely generated as an $A$ module?

**Geometrical interpretation**

When we denote $X = \operatorname{Spec}A$, $Y = \operatorname{Spec}B$, the module $M$ is regarded as a coherent sheaf $P$ on $X \times_k Y$ and the second condition in the question means

- $\operatorname{Supp}P$ is a graph of some map $\varphi$ from the closed points of $X$ to the ones of $Y$.

If we replace "map" by "morphism of varieties", $P$ seems to be the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\Gamma}$ of the graph of the morphism $\varphi \colon X \to Y$ or something like that ,and seemingly be finitely generated as an $\mathcal{O}_X$ module since the graph of $\varphi$ is isomorphic to $X$.

(Of course $P$ is not necessarily $\mathcal{O}_{\Gamma}$ itself or direct sum of that, but such example may help you to grasp th situation.)

Considering above interpretation, I think the proposition seems to be true but have no idea how to prove it.

Thank you for your any help!

Comment: Can you specify the $A$-module structure on $M$ and the $B$- module structure on $M\otimes _A A/ \mathfrak{p}$ ?

Comment: @Anirban Bose Both structures are induced from the $A \otimes B$ module structure of $M$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification